# A few questions related to starting to mine on a 4-5 GPU rig

Tags: mining

I have been doing some casual mining on my gaming PC. I have the basics down regarding hashrates, temps, power consumptions, etc. Now I am investing in building a 4-5 GPU rig and I have some questions.

1. Which GPU (barring availability issues) gives the most hashrate-per-dollar-per-watt value? It'd be better if you could name 2-3 in a descending order. As per my research, the 3060 Ti and the 1070 seem to be the most cost effective. If I go 1070, it will be a 6-GPU rig.
2. I have built a gaming PC from scratch several times, but never a rig that has more than 1 GPU/an open rig. What are the biggest challenges I face, given I have the essential knowhow of how PC hardware works.
3. Which mining pool and mining software are the best? I am open to installing something like HiveOS on this system if that gives any significant advantage. I've been mining currently using Nanominer only.
4. What are some optimizations important for mining? I believe there are more specific optimizations to improve the hashrate/mining efficiency?

Thanks

Comment: There aren't many miners here, perhaps you can get an answer in r/EtherMining.

Comment: @Ismael tried that. Was met with jokes and downvotes instantly. Deleted the post. Just a typical day on reddit.